# C++ Aribitrary(Dynamic) Type conversion

Tags: c++, templates

I have written an Adapter pattern for two types A and B that is suppose to adapt the types. This is just a normal template class. The problem is I need to convert from A and B. I do not know the types of A and B though but will supply them later on by specializing.

Is there a way to allow conversion from arbitrary A and B by telling C++ that a type converter will exist in the future, and if it doesn't then throw an error. (instead of just assuming there is no way to convert)

For example:

```
template<typename A, typename B> B Converter(A a) { return B(); }
```

This converter works with arbitrary types but obviously does not convert properly. I would then like to specify:

```
template<> int Converter(int a) { return a/2; }
template<> float Converter(bool a) { return (a) ? 0.45f : 12f; }
template<> int Converter(myType a) { return a.value; }

then, later one, by the "user"(after compilation) I would like to effectively create more converters. For example, I will allow the user to hook into my code and supply converters for their custom types.
```

I suppose I can modify

```
template<typename A, typename B> B Converter(A a) { `Find appropriate converter in list and use that` }
```

to be more complex but I'm looking for an efficient way to do this. In fact, I want to allow multiple converters of the same type to be used:

```
template<> int Converter(int a) { return a/4; }
```

(So, in one case I will use an int to int converter that cuts the value in half and in another case I will use a/4. I'll want to be able to change these dynamically. So I won't be using specialization really)

I simply want to plug in my type converters either at compile time(I'll write a few) or run-time(the user will write a few). I want these to be pretty fast and I want the converters I write to be faster since they are built in.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remember that templates is a pure compile-time construct, and that C++ is not a dynamic language where code can be constructed dynamically during runtime.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, BUT, I want to supply static template conversions. If I didn't care about extensibility then there wouldn't be an issue. I would just write all my conversions at compile time and use the above methods. I want to combine both worlds. It shouldn't be difficult in that I should be able to specialize in some way for compile time converters and "generalize" for dynamic converters.

Comment: One can already get this feature as I pointed out by specializing and then writing a general converter in the unspecified converter. The problem is I also want to somehow allow for multiple converters of the same definitions. e.g., `int myConverter1(int), int myConverter2(int)`. This too is not difficult by allowing hooks... but the whole method is relatively inefficient.

Comment: I guess you could work with an extra template parameter to choose between several same-signature converters. Can you post a piece of code which would be using your converters? I can't quite work out the desired use syntax from your question.

Comment: If you want a error for non compatible converts, just dont implement the generic case. However this interferes with your runtime option.

Comment: Why they must be templates? Can not you use traditional overloads like  `std::string toString( int x );`, `std::string toString( float y );` and `std::string toString( double z );` ? Are you aiming to fight strong types of C++?

Comment: @Angew: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563873/c-linkable-properties to see why I need them. I've found that you can sorta use a mash between templated function and standard functions and let the compiler decide which ones to use. Not sure if this will work well though.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Huh? What good will that do? What if someone adds a new type? What if I do not want to code all possible conversion types? The point of using templates is to allow me to code for some of the types that I want and leave the rest for the future. In your method, One will never be able to work on arbitrary types. i.e., it is not extensible. (if someone uses your code in a dynamic situation they won't be able to add their own objects to your system because you didn't provide them with a converter(obviously, how could you?).

Comment: Not sure what you are up to. If someone adds a type to your system, then with overloads they or you have to add overloads. With specializations they or you have to add specializations. Sure, you can add generic template overload (that should not attempt to do anything useful), but to achieve real conversions someone has to write real converters in either case.